# Debug Eclipse Console regexp

Tags: regex, eclipse, console

Since today, Eclipse locks up when an error is printed to the console during JUnit tests.

Using `jstat`, I can see that it hangs in `java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3782)`

How can I find out which regexp causes the problem?

Note that I didn't install anything nor did I change any prefs; my guess is that a change in the code triggered a lingering problem in an existing regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [Bug 175888 - ConsolePatternMatcher causes large delays with some large input](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=175888)

I have attached a patch which shows the regexp that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be something with a {}-quantifier (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/regex/Pattern$Curly.java.html). Posting the actual regexp will maybe help.